# Why Foreach Always Get The Last Value - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I changed my question, to make it easier to understand, here are my questions that I summarized into simpler code

### TestArray.php

```
<?php

//Product Header
$products = array(
    array(
        "id" => "ABC1",
        "name" => "Produk ABC1",
        "variations" => array(
            1,2,3
        )
    ),
    array(
        "id" => "ABC2",
        "name" => "Produk ABC2",
        "variations" => array(
            4,5
        )
    )
);

//Product detail that has variant detail
$productABC1 = array(
    array(
        "id" => 1,
        "sku" => "SKU1"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 2,
        "sku" => "SKU2"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 3,
        "sku" => "SKU3"
    )
);

//Product detail that has variant detail
$productABC2 = array(
    array(
        "id" => 4,
        "sku" => "SKU4"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 5,
        "sku" => "SKU5"
    )
);
```

### var_dump($products)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => ABC1
            [name] => Product ABC1
            [variations] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => ABC2
            [name] => Product ABC2
            [variations] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 5
                )

        )

)
```

### var_dump($productABC1)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [sku] => SKU1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [sku] => SKU2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [sku] => SKU3
        )

)
```

### var_dump($productABC2)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [sku] => SKU4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [sku] => SKU5
        )

)
```

how to add product name elements to each variation that have the same variation id number in the array of products? Thank you in advance

Comment: In your innermost `foreach()` you have `$data[$k][$l] = `, this will always overwrite the last value, try `$data[$k][$l][] = `

Comment: thanks for replying it @NigelRen but its give me a hundred of duplicated row, the name show but the sum of the row is getting more big than its to be

Comment: You are looping over your products in `$productHeader`, and in each iteration, you add a new API URL to fetch to `$urlProductVariant`, which you then loop over. So while processing the record for your first product, you will be making one API call, while processing the second one, you will be making two API calls (because `$urlProductVariant` now contains _two_ entries already), and so on and so forth. I doubt that is what you actually intended to do here?

Comment: eum yes thats gonna be like that, am i wrong? or there is a best practice? thanks before @CBroe

Comment: It is not really clear what kind of data you are trying to fetch here. But I guess you only need to make that call to fetch the product variations once per product? Then instead of `$urlProductVariant[$i] = …` and a loop over that array afterwards, this should just be `$curlVariant = …`, and the foreach loop over `$urlProductVariant` should be removed, execute what you currently have inside that loop only _once_ then.

Comment: IT seems that you just need to separate loops. First loop is for `$urlProductVariant` populating, then second one for processing this array

Comment: first im fetching from url header to get the product id and product name, the result of the first call is i had a product id and product name, then in the second call, i use the different url, that must be included with the product id, then i execute the second call, to get the sku variations, after that i build an array for put the value of the product name, and the sku

Comment: So put loops one by one, but not nested

Comment: okay i'll try it, thanks before @Banzay

Answer (score 0):

I think it shouldd look like:

```
// Iterate productHeader to get name, and id
$productName = array();
foreach ($productHeader as $product) {
    $productId = $product->id;
    $productName[ $productId ] = $product->name;
    $urlProductVariant[ $productId ] =  $client_url . '' . $pathProductHeader . '/' . $productId . '/variations?consumer_key=' . $client_key . '&consumer_secret=' . $client_secret;
}

// Iterate through dataProduct to cURL url variant
foreach ($urlProductVariant as $productId => $curlVariant) {
    $chVariant = curl_init($curlVariant);
    curl_setopt($chVariant, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($chVariant, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($chVariant, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($chVariant, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // Execute the curl
    $curl_response_variant = curl_exec($chVariant);
    // Decode the response and set to an array
    $productVariant[ $productId ] = json_decode($curl_response_variant);
}

// Iterate through productVariant to get data
foreach ($productVariant as $productId => $variant) {
    $sku = $variant->sku;
    // Get the individual name from the array productName
    $name = $productName[ $productId ];
    $data[] = array(
        "apikey" => $client_apikey,
        "managed_by" => "Batch Inbound",
        "code" => $sku,
        "name" => $name ." - ".$sku,
        "barcode" => $sku
    );
}
return $data;
```

Comment: thanks @Banzay, i have been already tried the above code, but it still give me the same result, this is the result [pict](https://ibb.co/NNTjDtP)

Comment: @ravimukti , but they have different ID($sku). Do you need to have array with unique `name` field?

Comment: @ravimukti , could you show `$curl_response_variant`?

Comment: I've changed answer, pls test

Comment: Hi @Banzay thanks for the reply, the new code give me an error null, in sku data, but i'll show you the response of the `$curl_response_variant` in this [pict](https://ibb.co/QJPgq5V)

Comment: so does `$curl_response_variant` contain array of arrays?

Comment: yes it is, woocommerce didnt have a variant name in the result, so i have to be put product name in the product variant, for example first result i get the product that is array of 9 index, then second call the result is had a multidimentional array, that has 9 index (parent array) first and each of 9 index has variational index, such as 4 or 6 index (child array) nested on it, what i expect to put the first 9 index, in every variational that the parent array match with the first call

Comment: i think it is little bit tricky, adding an array into an array